# How to exclude jars from ear

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3

I am bundling EAR from a WAR file. The JARS are placed both in WARFile/WEB-INF/lib folder as well as EARFile/lib folder with duplication.

Do we need the JARS again in EARFile/lib folder inspite of having in WARFile/WEB-INF/lib?

If we do not need in EAR/lib filder, How can we remove them? The EAR file size became double due to duplication JARs presence in both WAR and EAR.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the ear projects pom? Do you declare any dependencies in the ear project apart from the war?

Answer (score 2):

Good read here on "skinny" wars.  Basically, you put the jars in the ear, but not the war files:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html

Comment: Michael answer helped me to remove the jars from WAR/WEB-INF/lib and to have only in EARFile/lib.

Do we have any issues by having libraries in EARFile/lib?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't seen any errors using the ear this way.  The only time you'll have an issue is if you try to use one of the war files standalone outside the ear.  That won't work since you don't have the jars in the war.  If you need that...just have 2 artifacts built, one for the "skinny" war, and one for a full war.  And only include the "skinny" wars in your ear.

Answer (score -3):

You have to define the dependency to your war project in the following way:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>xyz-web</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

and furthermore you have to configure the ear plugin like the following:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <version>6</version>
      <modules>
        <!-- Register our War as a web module, and set the context root -->
        <webModule>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>xyz-web</artifactId>
          <contextRoot>/xyz</contextRoot>
        </webModule>
      </modules>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Already I have done it the above configuration both in WAR pom.xml and EAR pom.xml