# Exclude jars from existing ear using ant task

Tags: ant, ear

I need to update an existing ear file using ant task excluding some of the jar files, which will be available on WAS shared libraries. I don't want to create ear again, need to only update already built ear, as I have seen posts to update ear but those are creating a new ear. My problem is, i don't want to re-create the ear.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500289/how-to-exclude-jars-from-ear) is a way for doing it through maven, but I want to do it through ear task ant.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with re-creating the ear file? Do you even think it's possible to remove some part of a file without rewriting it?

Comment: The ear file is automatically generated, so I don't want to change its formation. I just want to update the contents of the ear, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199535/update-a-single-file-in-the-ear-file-in-a-better-way) but through ant script.

Comment: 7zip makes you think it updates files directly in the archive, but in reality, it doesn't. It re-creates the whole archive. Just create an ant task that extracts everything from the EAR into an empty, temporary folder, then updates or removes the files you want to update/remove, then recreates the ear file (which is just a zip file with a .ear extension) from the temporary directory content.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, i agree with your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ant ear, war, and jar tasks might be able to update ears, wars, and jars, but I wouldn't depend upon it. Creating ears is a very quick task -- a few brief seconds, so it was never an issue I explored.

If you can't recreate the ear because the files you need are no longer available, you can try unzipping the ear, set what you need, and rebuild it from scratch.

```
<unzip src="${ear.file}"
    destdir="${temp.location}"/>
<delete file="${ear.file}"/>

<here be dragons.../>

<zip destfile="${ear.file}"
    basedir="${temp.location}"/>
```

You could use `<patternset/>`s, or `<zipfileset/>`s to control what gets zipped and unzipped, but it's probably easier unzipping and rebuilding.

If it makes you feel better, you can use `<ear/>` instead of `<zip>`, but you'll have to specify the `appxml` parameter. It's just easier to use `<zip/>`.